# Why do we need to get rid of fever, whilst most of medical textbooks say it is a defense reaction of immune system

Tags: immune-system, fever, acetaminophen

Why is paracetamol prescribed in cases of every fever when fever actually helps the body and is in fact induced by the immune system?

Shouldn't it be better to let the immune system do its job?

Comment: Do you know what the complications of fever are? Do you know if decreasing fever delays the resolution of infections (which cause fever)? This question lacks evidence of any prior research, a reason on this site to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, in almost all cases, a fever should be left to run its course as it is a function of the bodies immune response.

Taking paracetamol to lower your temperature by a few degrees has a suppressive effect on the immune system response and therefore, the illness can be prolonged.

In rare cases does a fever reach such a high level that can cause permanent damage (above 104f).

In most cases, reason patients are given paracetamol when they have a fever is simply to reduce the discomfort they are feeling.

An excerpt from the sources below: "Both animal and human studies have demonstrated that fever suppression during viral infections...may increase morbidity and prolong the illness. As fever rises, so do antidiuretic hormone levels, leading to solute-free water retention – making conservative fluid management essential. Finally, fever inhibits gastrointestinal function as energy is reallocated to the immunological response, underscoring the need to work in concert with these physiological changes."

Sources -

[Fever: Could A Cardinal Sign of COVID-19 Infection Reduce Mortality?](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amjms.2021.01.004)

[Fever and the Thermal Regulation of Immunity](https://doi.org/10.1038/nri3843)